# highcharts live not working with DB

Tags: javascript, php, database, highcharts

i have sensor send data to database and store there and the data of sensor shows in a website as a chart but its not working
guys i want to make these codes working so how can i ?
p.s. the database store real time data and the chart display the values in real time also

this php code to fetch data from database .. which is `new.php`

```
 <?php
 require 'mysql0.php';

 $query="SELECT * FROM `pulsesensor`";
 if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
 {
         echo "query executed<br>";

 while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
{
        echo $query_execute['value'].'<br>';
       //echo $query_execute['date'].'<br>';
}    
} 
else 
{
      echo "query not exicuted";
} 

?>
```

and html code with is chart code is that

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 
   auto">
    </div>
<script>
 /** 
 * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout
 * to request again
 */
function requestData() {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'new.php',
    success: function(point) {
        var series = chart.series[0],
            shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is
                                             // longer than 20
        // add the point
        chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);
        // call it again after one second
        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
    },
    cache: false
});
}
 $(document).ready(function() {
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        events: {
            load: requestData
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live Heartbeats data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        maxZoom: 20 * 1000
    },
    yAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        title: {
            text: 'Value',
            margin: 80
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'heartbeats data',
        data: []
    }]
});
});
        </script>
```

the result is that

[image]

what is the wrong?

Comment: Please paste here example of your data passed to chart. Also look at console, are there any errors?

Comment: 71
74
78
73
71
69
73
66
66
72
68
68
68
66
64
70
67
66
51
70
68
67
74
71
67
51
75
69
54
68
these are some of data that should appear in chart .. the console mention errors for code im not using in this operation @stpoa so what i have to do ?

Comment: can you copy whole `new.php` output in exactly the same format?

Comment: @stpoa the data are too long the command can't handle it :( what to do :((

Comment: Just paste part of your data, you can modify backend to send part of it.

Comment: after using `JSON` the data become like that `{"value":"69"}{"value":"70"}{"value":"65"}{"value":"74"}{"value":"72"}{"value":"72"}{"value":"69"}{"value":"67"}{"value":"71"}{"value":"68"}{"value":"70"}{"value":"67"}{"value":"67"}{"value":"56"}{"value":"72"}{"value":"70"}{"value":"70"}{"value":"72"}{"value":"67"}{"value":"66"}{"value":"66"}{"value":"69"}{"value":"72"}{"value":"72"}{"value":"72"}{"value":"67"}{"value":"69"}` but the chart can not put them as points @stpoa

Comment: Above output is not valid JSON, you can validate JSON here: http://jsonlint.com/